# How to submit a link to StumbleUpon with a title

Tags: stumbleupon

I saw a solution that had this line to submit a site with a title:

```
http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=http://mysite.com&title=hello
```

But I can't make it use the title I provide in the line.
So I just get to the submission page and see my url, but without the title filled in anywhere. How can I submit the site with a title?

Answer (score 2):

You can't choose or select a custom title for a site you want to submit to StumbleUpon.

It will be chosen automatically from the page you're adding.

> #### [Can I change the title of a submitted article?](http://getsatisfaction.com/stumbleupon/topics/can_i_change_the_title_of_a_submitted_article#reply_6468740)
>
> a page title is picked up from the source code of the page itself, and cannot be changed once attributed.

The [reason is because it would be open to abuse](http://getsatisfaction.com/stumbleupon/topics/edit_the_title_of_a_link#reply_1408668).

If the page you want to include in your stumbles doesn't have a great title, you're either stuck with it or you could ask the owner of the page to provide a better title in the `<title></title>` tags.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, it makes sense. But what about Review field? Is that possible to fill that in? It's strange they suggest using title field in the url if it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: The review field will be what you think about the page, available for other stumblers to read and add theirs on. You can fill it in with whatever you feel like. @ser

Comment: I mean I am building an app with a textarea and want users to fill in some text there then clicking a button in my app's page would send the link and that textarea content to StumbleUpon as a submission.

Comment: Your follow up is a new question better asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: well then that's just stupid on Stumble's part.  Titles can be very programmer oriented and so it needs to be stated and for that site to pick it up.  What's the point of having crap that's been stumbled if no title or title is just the website name even though you've added a relevant and specific title in that page you stumbled upon.  Seems like that would be totally invaluable to Stumble upon not to pick up a decent title.  For example, right now all the stumble upons for dimecasts.net show the title as "DimeCAsts.net" what use is that!